# Is exception handling mandatory in MDC.remove() or MDC.put()?

Tags: java, exception, logging, thread-local, mdc

```java
import org.slf4j.MDC;

            MDC.put(ID1, id1);
        MDC.put(ID2, id2);
        MDC.put(ID3, id3);
        try {
              return joinPoint.proceed();
        } finally {
            MDC.remove(ID1);
            MDC.remove(ID2);
            MDC.remove(ID3);
        }
```

- Assuming there is a code as above,
  Exceptions can also occur for remove, put()
- If an exception occurs in the deletion process for id1, you cannot delete irrelevant id2,id3. To prevent this problem, do I have to take an additional process of taking and processing an exception for that part of the above code? Like the attached code
  The code below is only processed for ID1, but you need a try-catch statement every time you add it

```java
        MDC.put(ID1, id1);
        MDC.put(ID2, id2);
        MDC.put(ID3, id3);
        try {
              return joinPoint.proceed();
        } finally {
                try{
                     MDC.remove(ID1); 
                } finally {
                           MDC.remove(ID2);
                   MDC.remove(ID3);
                }
           
          
        }
```

- There's no compiler exception

---

If there's anything lacking in the question, please point it out. I'll reflect it and upload it again

Comment: "If there's anything lacking in the question, please point it out." - Which MDC class are you talking about?  What does the compiler say?

Comment: `import org.slf4j.MDC;`, 
There's no compiler exception.. thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: If there are no compiler errors (not exceptions!!) then there is no *linguistic* reason to catch the exceptions.  But I don't think that is what you are asking.  I think you are asking if it is necessary from the perspective of code correctness to do those `remove` calls.  That's a different question entirely.

Comment: afaik `remove` doesn't throw an exception. Only if the setup is wrong (but then it would already fail on the `put`, or if the `ID1` (the `key`) is `null` but then again it would fail already. In other situations it should fail silently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are actually asking about the correct way to do the removals.

If we assume that any of the `put` or `remove` calls can throw an exception, AND that not tidying up the MDC is unacceptable, then the correct way to write this would be:

```
try {
    MDC.put(ID1, id1);
    try {
        MDC.put(ID2, id2);
        try {
            MDC.put(ID3, id3);
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        } finally {
            MDC.remove(ID3);
        }
    } finally {
        MDC.remove(ID2);
    }
} finally {
    MDC.remove(ID1);
}
```

You can simplify this by using `putCloseable` instead of `put` as follows:

```
try (
    MDC.MDCCloseable c1 = MDC.putCloseable(ID1, id1);
    MDC.MDCCloseable c2 = MDC.putCloseable(ID2, id2);
    MDC.MDCCloseable c3 = MDC.putCloseable(ID3, id2);
) {
    return joinPoint.proceed();
}
```

The `putCloseable` variant returns an adapter that implements `Closeable` where the `close()` method performs the required `remove`.

On the other hand, if we treat the MDC javadocs as defining the behavior, then the only case where `remove` is *documented* to throw an exception is when the key is `null`.  You should be able to guarantee that `ID1`, `ID2` and `ID3` are not `null`.  If you can, the above code is unnecessary; i.e. your original version with a single `finally` should be fine.

Comment: This becomes easer with a try-with-resources and `putClosable`.